# Vue js: How to display list of components only when its required data is loaded from bakend?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am new to Vue js. There are some tabs on a page; one is the `Logs` tab which shows the audit logs. I need to display a list of data on this tab, however, the data is loaded once the user clicks on the `Logs` tab. The problem is I don't know how to display this data when it is changed (downloaded from the backend)

There is a data `auditLogs:[]` and this is the code

```
<el-tabs v-model="currentTab" @tab-click="handleClick">
  <el-tab-pane :label="Data" name="question">...</el-tab-pane>             
  <el-tab-pane :label="Messages" name="messages">...</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane :label="Logs" name="audit-logs">
    <QuestionAuditLogComponent v-for="log in auditLogs"
        :audit-log="log"></QuestionAuditLogComponent>
  </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```

This is the method

```
handleClick(tab, event) {
  if(tab.name === 'audit-logs' && this.audioLogs.length === 0)
  {
      this.fetchAuditLogs();
  }
},
fetchAuditLogs()
{
  axios.get(route('api.questions.logs',
      {
        'model':'question',
        'model_id': this.$route.params.questionId
      }))
      .then((response) => {
        this.audioLogs = response.data.outcome.data;
      });
},
```

and this is `QuestionAuditLogComponent` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Elastic LogID : {{ auditLog.id }}</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">Event: {{ auditLog.event }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">At: {{ auditLog.created_at }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">By: {{ auditLog.user_name }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Question: {{ auditLog.auditable_id }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "QuestionAuditLogComponent",
  props: {
    auditLog: Object,
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: @EstusFlask I am new to Vue js, may I have your solution as some snippet code?

Comment: This is what suspense is for. If you use a router then you can do do the request in router hook. Both options work with a router in Vue 3. Consider checking the existing questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175371/the-recommended-way-to-load-route-data-before-entering-the-route . It's unknown if you use options api on purpose or not. The recent examples you'll find are composition api

Comment: I think you have typeo. change audioLogs to auditLogs and tell me if it is fixed or not.

Comment: @AliBahrami No fixing the typo was not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just add condition to your component and it will show only when data.

```js
<el-tabs v-model="currentTab" @tab-click="handleClick">
  <el-tab-pane :label="Data" name="question">...</el-tab-pane>             
  <el-tab-pane :label="Messages" name="messages">...</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane :label="Logs" name="audit-logs" v-if="auditLogs.length>0">
    <QuestionAuditLogComponent v-for="log in auditLogs"
        :audit-log="log"></QuestionAuditLogComponent>
  </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```

Or you can add variable status what will change through axios request

```js
export default {
...
data(){return {status:'empty',statusText:{load:'load'// and other
}}
},
methods:{
...
fetchAuditLogs()
{
this.status='load'
  axios.get(route('api.questions.logs',
      {
        'model':'question',
        'model_id': this.$route.params.questionId
      }))
      .then((response) => {
        this.audioLogs = response.data.outcome.data;
this.status=this.audioLogs.length>0?"ok":"empty"
      }).catch(function (error) {this.status="error"});
},
...
},
...
```

template

```js
<el-tabs v-model="currentTab" @tab-click="handleClick">
  <el-tab-pane :label="Data" name="question">...</el-tab-pane>             
  <el-tab-pane :label="Messages" name="messages">...</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane :label="Logs" name="audit-logs" >
    <QuestionAuditLogComponent v-for="log in auditLogs"
        :audit-log="log" v-if="status=='ok'"></QuestionAuditLogComponent>
    <div v-else>{{statusText[status]}} </div>
  </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```